# Sending email via Gmail SMTP hangs indefinitely without error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application, I use emails (`System.Net.Mail`) primarily for account authentication. It's worked perfectly until recently, and I have no idea what happened. I didn't change anything even slightly related to emails, as far as I know.

When I try to step into the `SendAsync` call in the controller, it transfers control back to the browser where it hangs indefinitely. Eventually I have to stop and restart the application pool just to access any page, which takes a couple minutes (usually it can be turned back on almost instantly).

I have it set up to use a Google app password, which is a requirement (you get an error about security otherwise). It doesn't seem to even get as far as Google, since [the new app password hasn't been used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlWtd.png).

I've tried the TLS port as well as the SSL port. Last time I got it working was using TLS.

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SmtpUsername" value="email@gmail.com" />
    <add key="SmtpPassword" value="AppPassword" />
    <add key="SmtpSender" value="email@gmail.com" />
    <add key="SmtpHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <add key="SmtpPort" value="587" /> <!-- SSL: 465, TLS: 587 -->
    <add key="SmtpEnableSsl" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Email code:

```
public class EmailClient : SmtpClient
{
    public EmailClient()
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SmtpHost");
        Port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SmtpPort"));
        EnableSsl = bool.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SmtpEnableSsl"));
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SmtpUsername"),
                                            WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SmtpPassword"));
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        Timeout = 30000; // Waiting 30 seconds doesn't even end the "loading" status
    }
}

public class EmailMessage : MailMessage
{
    private bool isBodyHtml = true;

    public EmailMessage(string subject, string body, string recipients)
        : base(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SmtpSender"), recipients, subject, body)
    {
        IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
    }

    public EmailMessage(string subject, string body, IEnumerable<string> recipients)
        : base(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SmtpSender"), string.Join(",", recipients), subject, body)
    {
        IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
    }
}

public static class Email
{
    /// <param name="recipients">Comma-delimited list of email addresses</param>
    public static async Task SendAsync(string subject, string body, string recipients)
    {
        using (EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(subject, body, recipients))
        using (EmailClient client = new EmailClient())
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(msg);
        }
    }

    /// <param name="recipients">Collection of email addresses</param>
    public static async Task SendAsync(string subject, string body, IEnumerable<string> recipients)
    {
        using (EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(subject, body, recipients))
        using (EmailClient client = new EmailClient())
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
    {
        await Email.SendAsync("TEST", "test", "anaddress@gmail.com");
        return View(); // Never reaches this point
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here. As some answers allude, there was nothing wrong with my code. I'm not sure which of the below I had changed without retesting, but **this is what you must have to use Gmail SMTP**:

- Use TLS port 587
- Set `SmtpClient.EnableSsl` to `true`
- Enable MFA for the Google account and use an app password for the `SmtpClient.Credentials`. I needed to enable MFA to create an app password.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the [Documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) and see the **Gmail sending limits.** under *Gmail SMTP server* section.

Your code looks fine, the only thing I see is that you are enabling SSL, but using the port distained for 'TLS' so users who will use the SSL method, will engage in an issue.

Beside from that, nothing appears to the eye.

Comment: Yeah, the limit is 2000. I'm in the dozens. And yes, it's the TLS port, but the SSL port doesn't work either. It was set to the TLS port and SSL was enabled last time it was working. I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

There is standard way to send emails from ASP.NET.

**web.config**

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" password="password" port="587" userName="user@gmail.com"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

**.cs**

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient(); // no other code. 
var msg = CreateEmailMessage();
//I use try... catch
try{
   smtp.Send(msg);
   //return true; //if it is a separate function
}
catch(Exception ex){
   //return false; 
   //use ex.Message (or deeper) to send extra information
}
```

Note that Gmail doesn't except a sender other than `username`. If you want your addressee to answer to another address then use

```
msg.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(email, publicName));
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps it's because you didn't answer the question? The question is "why doesn't this work?" not "is there another way to store the settings?". Again, I can't speak for others, but this is certainly no worse than Selaka's, which was upvoted.